# Selecting max values from different columns and showing the result in a single row

Tags: sql

Hej,
This problem is about how effectively a 'operation theater' is being used per day. for that i need to find the max(anestesi start) , max(operation start), max(anestesti end) , max(operation end) per operation theater for a single day.

| PatientID | Operation No. | Op Theater | Anestesi Start | OpStart | OP End | Anestesi End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | AA001 | Op1 | 2023-03-23 08:02 | 2023-03-23 08:15 | 2023-04-11 09:21 | 2023-04-11 09:36 |
| 222 | BB002 | Op1 | 2023-03-23 10:16 | 2023-03-23 10:30 | 2023-04-11 11:30 | 2023-04-11 11:50 |
| 333 | CC003 | Op1 | 2023-03-23 12:30 | 2023-03-23 12:51 | 2023-04-11 13:49 | 2023-04-11 13:54 |
| 555 | DD001 | Op2 | 2023-03-23 08:12 | 2023-03-23 08:20 | 2023-04-11 09:21 | 2023-04-11 09:36 |
| 666 | EE002 | Op2 | 2023-03-23 10:16 | 2023-03-23 10:30 | 2023-04-11 11:30 | 2023-04-11 11:50 |
| 777 | FF003 | Op2 | 2023-03-23 12:30 | 2023-03-23 12:51 | 2023-04-11 13:55 | 2023-04-11 13:59 |

**Desired Result**

```
Op Theater   Max(Anestesti Start/day)  Max(Anestesi End/day)   Max(Opstart/day)       Max(Op End/day)
 Op1         2023-03-23 08:02              2023-04-11 13:54    2023-03-23 08:15   2023-04-11 13:49
 Op2         2023-03-23 08:12              2023-04-11 13:59    2023-03-23 08:20   2023-04-11 13:55
```

Comment: Poor sample table data, add some other dates as well.

Comment: Looks like you need **min** for start columns and **max** for end columns.